# Add control/warning icon to GUI in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

is it possible to add a little icon/"light" to the side or bottom of the Eclipse GUI which is opened by an plugin, and make it's appearance (color for example) depending on the state of a variable?

I don't know if it's clear what I want to achieve, [so here's a picutre (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xNsn.jpg). I want there to be such a red square, which turns green if my variable becomes true (and red again, if it's false).

The icon can be located anywhere to be honest.